# How to authenticate user/password for connecting DB2 using JAVA

Tags: java, database, db2

I am using `DB2 Express C 9.7.4`.

I have to create `connection with DB2 database using JAVA`. Before making connection i have to `validate DB2 user/password`.

Please suggest any DB2 command or any other alternative

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have to validate user/password before connecting? These are validated on connection. Check any JDBC exception for login failure instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an *attach* to the instance with the user's credentials. If the user belongs to sysadm, sysctrl, sysmaint or sysmon authorities (group), the user is "*validated*". Then, with these credentials the database could be created, but the user has to belong to sysadm or sysctrl.

For more information:
Create database http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html (See "Usage notes")
Attach command http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002010.html

Do not use "db2icrt" because this command is to create an instance, and you should probably already has one.

Same question in [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14732763)

Comment: The instance attach seems that should be via DB2 API, thus you have you use JNI. Attach http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001633.html Create database http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001446.html